# react native built-in global objects does not exist at testing usinfg jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, global

react native built-in global objects like `WebSocket` does not exist in runnig jest's test

i'm testin my RN app using jest . trying to access RN built-in global `WebSocket` Object in test files give me undefined. whereas access the object in running app has no problem

app.test.js

```
console.log(typeof WebSocekt);// return undefined
```

app.js

```
console.log(typeof WebSocekt);// return function
```

expected the `WebSocket` in jest runner to be `function` but got `undefined` as result.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-websocket-mock to rescue

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `WebSocket` class doesn't exist globally inside `nodejs`, but in browsers it does. You can specify the `WebSocket` you want to use in the constructor like this:

```
const asteroid = require('asteroid');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const Connection = asteroid.createClass()

const portal = new Connection({
  endpoint: 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket',
  SocketConstructor: WebSocket // <-------------- HERE
})
```